# How to mock module local variable

Tags: mocking, pytest

I have setup similar to the below, I have simplified the case.

**script.py**

```
my_var = os.getenv("my_variable")

def my_func():
    my_var = my_var+"_new"
    print(my_var)
    return my_var
```

**script_test.py**

```
@patch('utils.script.my_var',"this_is_a_test_variable")
def test_get_duration_paths_v1(path):
    x =  my_func()
    print("variable is", x)
```

when I run the test case, it throws, `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'my_var' referenced before assignment`

Answer (score 0):

your specific issue is not related to mocking, it's a result of variable [scope](https://realpython.com/python-scope-legb-rule/)

You can remedy this by adding the `global` keyword inside of your function, or better yet: use different variable names.

```
env_var = os.getenv("my_variable")

def my_func():
    my_var = env_var + "_new"
    return my_var
```